# mapping many to many items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using database that looks like this the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Students(
    [StudentId] [int],
    ...,
    [MajorId] [int]
);
CREATE TABLE Majors(
    [MajorId] [int],
    ...,
    [MajorDes] [varchar](20)
);
CREATE TABLE CourseRequiredForEachMajor(
    [MajorId] [int],
    ...,
    [CourseTitle] [varchar](20)
);

CREATE TABLE CoursesCompletedByStudents(
    [StudentId] [int],
    ...,
    [CourseTitle][varchar] (20)
);
INSERT INTO Majors ([MajorId] , .. , [MajorDes]) VALUES (1, ... . 'IT');

INSERT INTO Students ([StudentId], .. , [MajorId]) VALUES (1, ... . 1);

INSERT INTO CourseRequiredForEachMajor ([MajorId], .. , [CourseTitle]) VALUES (1, ... . 'IT101');
INSERT INTO CourseRequiredForEachMajor ([MajorId], .. , [CourseTitle]) VALUES (1,...,'IT302');
INSERT INTO CourseRequiredForEachMajor ([MajorId], .. , [CourseTitle]) VALUES(1,...,'IT321');

INSERT INTO CoursesCompletedByStudents ([StudentId], .. , [CourseTitle]) VALUES (1, ... . 'IT101');
INSERT INTO CoursesCompletedByStudents ([StudentId], .. , [CourseTitle]) VALUES (1,...,'IT302');
INSERT INTO CoursesCompletedByStudents ([StudentId], .. , [CourseTitle]) VALUES(2,...,'IT321');
```

I'm trying to list the missing courses for each student in order to complete the all the requirements for each major ( e.g. in the image above, I want to say that studentId# 1 need to take course IT321 in order to complete all requirement for majorId #1 ). 
Also is there anyway that I can do to show percentage of completion ? ( e.g. studentId#1 completed two courses ( 66.6% ) out of 3 courses that are required by the major ). what is the way to do the calculations of this.

I really have no idea how to solve this, but this is my attempt:

```
Select CoursesCompletedByStudents.CourseTitle from Students,MajorsCourseRequiredForEachMajor,CoursesCompletedByStudents
 where Students.MajorId= Major.MajorId and Studetns.StudentId = CoursesCompletedByStudents.[StudentId]
 and CourseRequiredForEachMajor.[CourseTitle]=CoursesCompletedByStudents.[CourseTitle]
```

Comment: Please don't post images of table. Post `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements. Please also reveal what you have tried so far and the specific problem you got with your attempt.

Comment: @stickybit thanks for your reply. I've made the changes as requested.

Answer (score 0):

This query would give the required result.

```
with coursesCTE as 
(
Select StudentId,  CourseTitle, m.MajorId
from Students s
join Majors m
on s.MajorId = m.MajorID
join CourseRequiredForEachMajor cr
on cr.MajorId = m.MajorID
), 
completedCTE
as
(
Select StudentId,  cc.courseTitle, MajorId 
from CoursesCompletedByStudents cc
join CourseRequiredForEachMajor cm
on cc.CourseTitle = cm.CourseTitle
)
Select * from coursesCTE 
except 
Select * from completedCTE
```

If you want comma separated course Ids, you can use the Stuff/XML path hack or STRING_AGG if you're using SQL Server 2017